# Compare two columns in a table and get the similar and non-similar value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table consisting of two column.First column has 2500 integer value and second column has 1755 integer value. I'd like to compare both column and want to see the matching and non matching values.Please assist.

Comment: column1   Column2, this two column has all the integer values. I need to find the matching and non-matching value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in spreadsheet comparator in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2) col, IF(col1 = col2, TRUE, FALSE) match
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM `project.dataset.table`) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM `project.dataset.table`) 
ON col1 = col2
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 8
)
SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2) col, IF(col1 = col2, TRUE, FALSE) match
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM `project.dataset.table`) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM `project.dataset.table`) 
ON col1 = col2
```

with output

```
Row col match    
1   1   false    
2   2   true     
3   3   false    
4   4   true     
5   6   false    
6   8   false
```